# jasmine unit testing angular directive using $parsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having an issue figuring out the unit test for a directive that takes the input and replaces anything that isn't a digit with an empty string.  I'm getting the error `undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'input.val('1').trigger('input')')`

The issue is on the trigger.  input.val returns an empty string.  If I don't do the trigger my $parser function code isn't called.

It works when testing in my app, just can't get my head around how to test it.

I know it is using the directive as when I take out the `ng-model` the test fails with `number-only requires ngModel`

I want to have a two tests:

- enter a number, view value is a number
- enter a letter, view value is an empty string.

Here is my directive

```
/**
 * @ngdoc object
 * @name components-helpers-number-only
 * @description
 *
 * Catch the value before it reaches the model in the parsers phase
 * replace any non digit (0-9) and replace with an empty string.  
 * This works for any input method.  Copy and paste / Dragon etc.
 *
 */
angular.module('components-helpers-number-only', [])
    /**
     * @ngdoc directive
     * @name components-helpers-number-only.directive:numberOnly
     * @restrict E
     * @replace true
     * @element ANY
     *
     * @description
     * Directive to display a standard number field,
     * along with binding and validation, link function initialises the controller passing references to all required resources
     *
     */
    .directive('numberOnly', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
                // The parsers are before assigning a value to a model
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                    // Replace anything apart from a value 0-9 with an empty string
                    var transformedInput = inputValue.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                    // If the values are the same no need to change the value.
                    if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModel.$render();
                    }

                    return transformedInput;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Here is my unit test

```
describe('Directive: numberOnlyDirective', function () {
    'use strict';

    var scope;
    var dummyElement1;
    var input;
    var ngModel;

    beforeEach(module('components-helpers-number-only'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        dummyElement1 = angular.element(
            '<input type="text" ng-model="model" value="1" number-only />'
        );

        input = $compile(dummyElement1)(scope);

        ngModel = input.controller('ngModel');

    }))


    it('should define an input with number only directive', function () {
        expect(input).toBeDefined()



    });

    it('should set the value to 1 and set the view value to 1', function () {
        input.val('1').trigger('input');
        scope.$apply()
    });

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because Angular's jqLite doesn't have [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), it only supports [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).  Compare what jQ methods are implemented on the [`angular.element` documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

One potential way to double check if this is the case is to temporarily include jQuery in your tests.  AngularJS will use the full jQuery instead of jqLite if it is available.  If your test works at that point, that is the likely issue in which case you can see if `.triggerHandler()` will still fulfill your need.

Comment: Yeah that was it.  ```triggerHandler()``` works as expected :)  Thanks!